# Complex Numbers, Argand Diagrams

Tags: complex-numbers

Is it possible to tell if |3-4i| is greater than |1+2i| based entirely from viewing their plotted positions on an Argand diagram?

Comment: And in cases where it's not obvious, take a compass and draw a circle.

Answer (score 1):

It is visually obvious that $(3,-4)$ is quite a bit further from the origin than $(1,2)$. (Recall that if $z=a+bi$. then $|z|$ is the distance from $(a.b)$ to the origin.)